# TypeError: Cannot read property 'skills' of null

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

```
const skillsSchema = {
    title: String,
    description: String,
};

const Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillsSchema);

const teacherSchema = {
    profession: String,
    teacherFName: String,
    bornDate: Number,
    priceperhour: Number,
    videolink: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    skills: [skillsSchema],
};

const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);

app.post('/taddcourse', function (req, res) {
    const title = req.body.courseTitle;
    const discription = req.body.courseBody;
    const teacherName = req.body.teacher;

    const skill = new Skill({
        title: title,
        description: discription,
    });

    Teacher.findOne({ teacherFName: teacherName })
        .then(function (foundTeacher) {
            foundTeacher.skills.push(skill);
            foundTeacher.save();
            res.render('teacherdash', {
                teachName: foundTeacher.teacherFName,
                courses: foundTeacher.skills,
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

when I try to run the code this error appears
TypeError: Cannot read property 'skills' of null.

I want to push a skill for each teacher in this line
foundTeacher.skills.push(skill);
but I dont know why this error appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the following changes:

1-) You need the setup schemas using `new mongoose.Schema(...)`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const skillsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
});

const Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillsSchema);

const teacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    profession: String,
    teacherFName: String,
    bornDate: Number,
    priceperhour: Number,
    videolink: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    skills: [skillsSchema],
});

const Teacher = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);
```

2-) To add a skill to a teacher you can use `findOneAndUpdate` with the push operator.

```
app.post('/taddcourse', async function (req, res) {
    const title = req.body.courseTitle;
    const discription = req.body.courseBody;
    const teacherName = req.body.teacher;

    const skill = new Skill({
        title: title,
        description: discription,
    });

    try {
        const foundTeacher = await Teacher.findOneAndUpdate(
            { teacherFName: teacherName },
            {
                $push: {
                    skills: skill,
                },
            },
            {
                new: true,
            }
        );

        res.render('teacherdash', {
            teachName: foundTeacher.teacherFName,
            courses: foundTeacher.skills,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like no object was found with provided teachername. Try checking the name in the database also the err object